# Assignment Problem (Linear Programming, Genetic Algorithm, etc.)

Tags: r, optimization, genetic-algorithms, operations-research, linear-programming

I'm looking for advice on how I should approach a specific problem. Some background first:

The problem is about shipments falling into a bin. There are 19 such bins, which are further sorted into 20 different bags (each having a unique id) on each bin. We have the data for the number of shipments falling into a bin, and the data for number of shipments falling into each bag. Now there is great variation between the number of shipments falling into each bin. I need to make an algorithm/model that can heuristically balance the load between the bins.

I will be attaching a picture showing the sample of the exact data below.  The bins are given an id from 2-20. The bags also have a unique id (for example 10381, 10382, etc). We also have the number of shipments (called 'count of awb') falling into each bag and the bin that the bag is located in.

Now, our constraints are that the 'count of awb' corresponding to each bag id is fixed. The number of bags within a bin are also fixed (20 to be precise). The only way we are allowed to solve this problem is by rearranging the bags between the bins. Do note that we don't need an exact solution, i.e., the number of shipments to be exactly equal for all the bins. Currently, the highest bin has 43200 shipments falling into it, whereas the lowest has only 5792 shipments falling into it. The mean across all the bins is 22780 shipments. So we want each bin to be as close as possible to this number, while reducing the variation between the bins. I am attaching a portion of the data for reference. [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are probably computation efficiencies available via some technique I'd have to think more about (ILP approaches mainly), but if you just want to solve the problem via a heuristic search, I would generate a representation like the following:

First, label each of your "bags" as a number between 0 and $n-1$, where $n=19*20=380$ (the total number of bags). Let P then be a vector of 380 integers, each getting a value between 2 and 20 inclusive. The interpretation is that $P[i]=k$ indicates bag ID $i$ goes into bin $k$.

Your objective function $f(P)$ takes such a vector and calculates something like the variance of your "count of awb" metric across each of the 19 bins. I don't know enough of your problem to be more specific than that, but the idea is that you would define a function such that minimizing (or maximizing) that function would give you a desired outcome.

Now you have a representation scheme and a fitness function. Before I'd go crazy with it, I'd probably just try a fairly simple hill climber. Generate a random solution, and then start trying systematically to move a single bag from one bin to another as your local search neighborhood generator. You could try to get fancier and randomly generate a bunch of possible $P$ vectors, define crossover and mutation operators, and build up a genetic algorithm instead, or try a tabu search or simulated annealing method. Once you have a representation and objective function, there's pretty green field of ideas you can apply without much effort.